# Selecting the last row using VBA and copying down

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I need to select the last row in my spreadsheet with values and then drag it down (including formulas). I am able to find the last row with values but am having issues selecting this last row.

```
With Sheets("Data")
    Dim LR1 As Long
    LR1 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   .Range(LR1).Select
End With
```

I just want this last row selected and dragged down 1 row. I haven't attempted to add code to drag down because I can't seem to select the last row of data.

Comment: I think you want `.Range("A:" & LR1).Select`

Comment: You define LR1 as long and get the last row using it ... but then you use `.Range(LastRow).Select` instead of `.Range("A" & LR1).Select`

Comment: 6 seconds faster than me findwindow but you need to edit your variable name ;)

Comment: Unbroken you edited your answer but now you're using `.Range(LR1).Select` instead of `.Range("A" & LR1).Select` - LR1 is simply a number, so if you want `.Range("A100").Select` for example, you use `.Range("A" & LR1).Select`

Comment: I would like to select the row that is found using the command `LR1 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

if i change `.Range(LR1).Select` with `.Range("A" & LR1).Select` I receive an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted to autofill your last cell into the cell below it,

```
Sub Data_Button1_Click()
    Dim LR1 As Long

    With Sheets("Data")
        LR1 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With .Range("A" & LR1)
            .AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A1:A2")
        End With

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: appreciate the help but this gives me an error saying a variable is not defined. I think it has to do with the destination.

Comment: Is that what is highlighted in the debug?

Comment: Actually, seems to have worked now. Thanks! Is there a way to copy down the entire row and not just the first column?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this with the code below. Thanks everyone for your help along the way.

```
Dim LR1 As Long

With Sheets("Auto Lease Data")
   LR1 = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   With .Range("A" & LR1 & ":ZZ" & LR1)
       .AutoFill Destination:=.Range("A1:ZZ2"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With
End With
```